# implementating the bayesian linear prediction with NIG prior

Tags: regression, machine-learning, bayesian, conjugate-prior

In Bayesian linear regression when the covariance of weights is unknown; one can set Normal-Inverse-Gamma prior.

Based on "Machine Learning: a Probabilistic Perspective", Page 235,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
p(\mathbf{w},\sigma^2|D) &= \mathrm{NIG}(\mathbf{w}, \sigma^2 | \mathbf{w}_N, \mathbf{V}_N, a_N, b_N) \\
\mathbf{w}_N &= \mathbf{V}_N( \mathbf{V}_0^{-1}\mathbf{w}_0 + \mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{y}) \\
\mathbf{V}_N &= (\mathbf{V}_0^{-1} + \mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{X} )^{-1}\\
a_N &= a_0 + n/2 \\
b_N &= b_0 + \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{w}^{\mathrm{T}}_0\mathbf{V}^{-1}_0\mathbf{w}_0 + \mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{w}^{\mathrm{T}}_N \mathbf{V}_N^{-1}\mathbf{w}_{N} ) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

And drives the posterior with this prior and likelihood, we should be able to derive the following posterior as following,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
p(\mathbf{w},\sigma^2|D) &= \mathrm{NIG}(\mathbf{w}, \sigma^2 | \mathbf{w}_N, \mathbf{V}_N, a_N, b_N) \\
\mathbf{w}_N &= \mathbf{V}_N( \mathbf{V}_0^{-1}\mathbf{w}_0 + \mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{y}) \\
\mathbf{V}_N &= (\mathbf{V}_0^{-1} + \mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{X} )^{-1}\\
a_N &= a_0 + n/2 \\
b_N &= b_0 + \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{w}^{\mathrm{T}}_0\mathbf{V}^{-1}_0\mathbf{w}_0 + \mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{w}^{\mathrm{T}}_N \mathbf{V}_N^{-1}\mathbf{w}_{N} ) \\
&=\cdots \\
p(\sigma^2|D) &= \mathrm{IG}(a_N, b_N) \\
p(\mathbf{w}|D) &= \tau(\mathbf{w}_N, \frac{b_N}{a_N}\mathbf{V}_N, 2a_N)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

When I look at the implementation [here](https://github.com/probml/pmtk3/blob/202325ce4dcc75d86d74103e873fdb97ae6b26a4/toolbox/BasicModels/sub/normalEqnsBayes.m); I get really confused ! It is not a 1-1 match with the book. I tried to implement the formula in matlab by myself which you can find it here.

```
clear, clc
x = randn(20, 3);
w_true = [2,5,1]';
y = x * w_true + rand(20, 1);

V0 = zeros(3);
w0 = [0,0,0]';
a0 = 0.001;
b0 = 4;



for cnt = 1:100
    vN = inv(inv(V0) + x'*x ) ;
    wN = vN * (inv(V0)*w0 + x'*y);
    aN = a0 + cnt/2;
    bN = b0 + 0.5 * (w0'*inv(V0)*w0 + y'*y - wN'*inv(vN)*wN);

    V0 = vN;
    w0 = wN;
    a0 = aN;
    b0 = bN;
end
sig=1./gamrnd(a0,1./b0) %inverse gamma
```

However, $b_n$ tends to get very large and basically, the code does not meet the formula. Also I am not sure about the t-student distribution in Matlab.

I appreciate if you make some comments on the implementation of this model, either by helping me to improve my code, or explaining on the author's code

Comment: One thing is that you have matrix transposes where you should have matrix inverses.

Comment: ooops - you are write ! Still ! I should add that, I am not sure about the t-student test distribution in Matlab either! I updated the question(code).

Comment: any comment on the t distribution ?!